# Chrome: Re-select other certificate for same website

Tags: google-chrome

Anyone know if it is possible to re-select the used certificate in Chrome on the same website where a certificate has already been selected in the session without restarting Chrome ?
I have multiple personal certificates for one website and don`t know how, if at all possible, to get the "select certificate popup" a second (third...) time in one session to choose a different certificate.

Searching on StackOverflow and Google I only find errors in general certificate use and some completely different discussions.